# OOP: Inverse of Aggregation?

Tags: oop

In **OOP** when a class forms a `HAS-A` relationship with another class, it's called an `Aggregation`, a simple example of that is below where a `Car` has an `Engine` but an engine can exist without a car:

```
class Engine {
    start() {
        console.log('Engine started');
    }
}

class Car {

    engine: Engine;

    constructor(engine: Engine) {
        this.engine = engine;
    }
}
```

### Question:

If i had to do the inverse of `Aggregation` such that i could answer a query `Give me all the cars associated with this Engine`, what is that called in OOP?

Answer (score 0):

The aggregation (or composition, or association) is a concept: it allows to say that A has a B. You can invert the composition (B has an A) but the concept itself has no "inverse". Or it would be: A does not have B !

Answer (score 0):

***has-a*** as a static relationship gets translated to Aggregation. In a typical Object oriented modeling, after identifying the static relationship between two entities, next question we ask is which is more frequent direction in which we will be raising the queries.

In your example it is one-to-one relationship between objects (vehicle has only one engine and engine is mounted on only one vehicle at given moment).

If most of the time the query is *getMeThisVehiclesEngine()* (container to contained), then Vehicle holds the reference of engine, if the query is opposite (I think this is kind of your inverse) like *getMeTheVehicleWhichIsHoldingThisEngine()* (content to container. Here ***container*** and ***content*** terms are from the domain perspective), then engine will hold the reference of vehicle, and I would call it association. If we need bidirectional navigation, both objects keep each others reference. (In general we avoid bidirectional relationship). with one to one relationship, its not that obvious, but imagine an example of shared aggregation with *has-a* relationship between Athletics Team and member-student. member-students can be part of different teams simultaneously. From team to student-member I would call it as aggregation and Team will hold collection of Students. From Student-member to Team I would call it association (Student is associated with Athletics Team) and Student will hold either simple reference of Athletics team, or collection of Teams, if Student can be member of multiple teams simultaneously.